# Concatenate tables in one and insert it in Google Spreesheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've got this basic script for Google Sheets, in G.Script

```
  var a = [['1','2']];

  for (var i = 0; i <5; i++){
    var range = sheet.getRange("A"+i+":B"+i);
    range.setValues(a);
  }
```

As you can see, I write 5 times the table "a" in the sheet. What I'd like in concatenate all the tables "a" in one table and write this table, once in the sheet.

I've tried with concat(), but it does not work. So maybe I don't use it properly.

Could you please help me ? 
Many thanks
B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you create your spreadsheet range based on the size of your array "a".  Rather than creating a cell range such as A1:B5, I recommend using number values to define the range that you would like to update.

Also, updates to Google Sheets run much faster if you update an entire range at one time.

```
function myFunction() {
  var data = [];
  data.push([1,2]);
  data.push([2,3]);
  data.push([3,4]);
  if (data.length > 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
      .getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length)
      .setValues(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpul. Where I'm strungeling, is to build the mega table, with a loop. In my example data looks like [[[[1, 2], [1, 2]], [1, 2]], [1, 2]] - and my code is                       table = a;
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
    
    table = [table,a];
    Logger.log(table);

  }  - What I'm missing ? Thx again

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you.